# How do I add incremental numbers in the middle of a sequence?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-365

`MPP1-302-US` - I want to easily make the column go
`MPP2-302-US`,
`MPP3-302-US`, etc.

without having to split the data.  Is this possible? If so, what is the formula?

Answer (score 0):

English Excel Forumla (non-tested) :

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A2,3),NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-7),LEN(A2)-10))+1,RIGHT(A2,7))
```

French (tested) :

```
=CONCATENER(GAUCHE(A2;3);VALEURNOMBRE(DROITE(GAUCHE(A2;NBCAR(A2)-7);NBCAR(A2)-10))+1;DROITE(A2;7))
```

Result :

```
MPP2-302-US
MPP3-302-US
MPP4-302-US
MPP5-302-US
MPP6-302-US
MPP7-302-US
MPP8-302-US
MPP9-302-US
MPP10-302-US
MPP11-302-US
MPP12-302-US
MPP13-302-US
MPP14-302-US
MPP15-302-US
MPP16-302-US
MPP17-302-US
MPP18-302-US
MPP19-302-US
MPP20-302-US
MPP21-302-US
MPP22-302-US
MPP23-302-US
MPP24-302-US
MPP25-302-US
MPP26-302-US
MPP27-302-US
MPP28-302-US
...
```